# _app.default.messaging.notifications is not a function by migrating to v6 of react-native-firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I flow the docs and migrate my app to version 6 but I get this error

```
TypeError: _app.default.messaging.notifications is not a function.
 (In '_app.default.messaging.notifications()', '_app.default.messaging.notifications' is undefined)
```

here is my code
I kept everything like it used to be should I do something else

```
.
.
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
.
.


    firebase.messaging.notifications().onNotification(Notification => {
        var messageData = Notification.data;
        var messageType = messageData.type;

        var DBbadgeCount = parseInt(messageData.badgeCount);
            this.props.Increment_RequestCount();
            firebase.messaging
                .notifications()
                .getBadge()
                .then(count => {
                    if (count !== DBbadgeCount) {
                        firebase.messaging.notifications().setBadge(DBbadgeCount);
                    }
                })
                .then(() => { })
                .catch(error => { });
```

what should I do now?

Comment: Read the document carefully: https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage#foreground-state-messages

Answer (score 0):

v6 split up the packages, and you no longer import messaging from app, but from the `@react-native-firebase/messaging` package instead.  `@react-native-firebase/app` just needs to be installed, but you don't need to import it.

```
.
.
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
.
.
   messaging.notifications().onNotification(Notification => {
        var messageData = Notification.data;
        var messageType = messageData.type;

        var DBbadgeCount = parseInt(messageData.badgeCount);
            this.props.Increment_RequestCount();
           messaging
                .notifications()
                .getBadge()
                .then(count => {
                    if (count !== DBbadgeCount) {
                       messaging.notifications().setBadge(DBbadgeCount);
                    }
                })
                .then(() => { })
                .catch(error => { });
```